# Regular expression to select set of numbers

Tags: regex

I want to get a set of numbers (3 digits) from a string. But some numbers bind with specific text and those numbers don't need to be include in the output.

Input:

```
C123456  577 abcd 173944 C5678541883
```

Result should to be:

```
577 173 944 188
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with EE, but regex.

Comment: I agree - nothing to do with EE

Comment: Stackoweflow question... Dont ask in EE forum

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: What are the rules for extraction? It's not clear how you came up with your results.

Comment: Why `188` but not `418`?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand why you want the 188 on the end.  It doesn't seem to match any rule.  Even a regex needs some kind of uniformity

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you only want to match full numbers without any other characters, separated by white space. If you really want to capture and `188` too and `173944` split into two parts, you can provide a comment below with more information about what it actually should match (numbers with 3 or 6 characters, numbers etc.)

So, to extract all numbers from a white-space separated string, you can use the following regular expression. Make sure to use the global flag `/g`:

```
\b([0-9]+)\b
```

Here is a live example:

```js
var text = "C123456  577 abcd 173944 C5678541883";
var regex = /\b([0-9]+)\b/g;

var match = regex.exec(text);
while(match !== null) {
   console.log(match[1]);
   match = regex.exec(text);
}
```